# SFTP proxy with routing to correct SFTP server

Tags: java, ssh, proxy, routes, sftp

We have two SFTP servers, let's say *Server A* and *Server B*. At this moment our users use only *Server A* to upload/download the data. Our goal is to slowly start moving the users to *Server B*, but the requirement is that users should not be aware of this. So what we need is some kind of "proxy" or "router", let me describe how it should work.

We need to develop the application, that will be sitting in front of these two servers and users will access only this application via SFTP, not *Server A* or *Server B* directly.
From clients/users point of view this application has to behave as a normal SFTP server, but under the hood is has to do the following:

1. Read the username and password provided by user
2. Based on the credentials we will know whether we should connect with Server A or Server B
3. Establish SFTP connection with the correct server and route all the communication to the correct server

This way we can slightly migrate users from *Server A* to *Server B* and users will not be aware of that, they do not have to change their connection details.

We had to do exactly the same exercise with FTP servers, which was pretty easy because it is easy to read FTP communication. We have implemented that in Java, simply with two instances of `Socket`, one between the client and our application, the second between our application and FTP server. *(It wasn't so easy, we had to also do a proxy for the data channel, but there was no issue with that.)*

Do you have any idea how we can achieve the same with SFTP? I am not asking for a specific code example, it's a more generic question, what should be the best approach.

Comment: This is not really a programming question. This might help you (combined with `Match user` directive): [Seamless SFTP tunneling / jump box](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/510258/119732).

Comment: You are right, it's not a programming question. Maybe I was "blind" because we developed the exact same solution for FTP, so our first direction was to try the same for sFTP. I did not know about the possibility you mentioned. Thanks for that, I'll check that!